# How to connect AIR application to Java server using UDP DatagramSocket?

Tags: java, actionscript-3, sockets, udp, datagram

I'm trying to connect a Flash AIR application with a Java server using UDP DatagramSocket, but I don't have a clue how to do it. Can someone help?

Comment: Do you have any code to show? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [DatagramSocket](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/DatagramSocket.html) class.

Here you have video called [ADC Presents - Discover the UDP API in Adobe AIR 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cit8qVkA4cA). This helped me to work with UDP in AIR, so I hope you'll find it usefull too.